# How to display generate random number on screen

Tags: android, layout, random, numbers, imageview

I'm trying to create an app that will generate random number. I found this generate number coding and it is working perfectly. However I have problem when I want to display the generate number to the layout.

For example, the generator will generate two numbers ; numberOne=3 and numberTwo=1. Then it will display imageview number 3 and imageview number 1 on the layout page. Since I'm new to this so how can I display the imageview of the numbers based on the number being generated. Thanks :)

**Generate number coding**

```
Random randomNum=new Random();
int numberOne;

numberOne=1+randomNum.nextInt(10);
System.out.println(numberOne + " ");
```

**This is the example of the display**

[image: This is the example of the display]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load the image into already defined ImageView.

```
// fetch image resource id
// first parameter is the image name without the extension
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
// assign it to ImageView
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```